# Подсчет оборотов двигателя по времени между началом и концом оборота

Tags: c++, arduino

Пытаюсь сделать счетчик оборотов на ардуино в реальном времени.

Имеется время 1 оборота двигателя (в микросекундах), двигатель дает 1 импульс на 1 оборот.

Как высчитать кол-во оборотов в минуту, зная лишь время 1 оборота?

Код:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

long lastRpmDetectedTime = 0;
long lastRPM = 0;

double rpm = 0;

void rpmDetected(){
  detachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2));
  lastRPM = micros() - lastRpmDetectedTime;

  rpm = lastRPM; // нужна какая-то магия превращения разницы во времени в обороты в минуту

  lastRpmDetectedTime = micros();
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), rpmDetected, RISING);  
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), rpmDetected, RISING);  
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(rpm);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Герцы классе в седьмом, наверное, проходят. А даже если уже и не проходят, то можно и самостоятельно сообразить, как "высчитать кол-во оборотов в минуту, зная лишь время 1 оборота" . Если один оборот двигатель совершает за 30 секунд (это 30_000_000 микросекунд), то сколько будет в минуту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поделить минуту на микросекунды и поделить на время оборота(тоже в микросекундах).

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, пример кода привести? Не очень понимаю что значит "минуту на микросекунды"

Comment: @user300058, разделите 60000000 (столько микросекунд в минуте) на время одного оборота в микросекундах